# htaccess internal redirect from subdomain to root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I want to redirect internally everything from static.domain.com to www.domain.com. Please note that static.domain.com is an existing subdomain, I don't want to use wildcards. I've used this code in the subdomain's .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^static\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301]
```

but i get the error:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: in my root i have an index.php that handles my application framework.

it looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
```

My static subdomain contains only a .htaccess file that looked exactly like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^static\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301]
```

I added `RewriteEngine On` and now it redirects me externally (if i request static.domain.com/css/style.css it takes me to domain.com/css/style.css). I would like to redirect internally (the address in the browser shouldn't change).

---

### Solution

Studied a bit the apache RewriteRule Flags and found the solution. I used the P flag for proxy. Here is the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^static\.outletika\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://outletika.com/$1 [R=301,P]
```

Comment: do you have an `index` page in your root?

Comment: You also need a `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: You're redirecting to `domain.com`.  Didn't you say that you wanted to redirect to www.domain.com?  Do you get the same error if you do a direct request to http://domain.com/somevaliduri

Comment: i updated with some more details, it seems to redirect externally now

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer and accept it so the question appears resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct solution:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^static\.outletika\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://outletika.com/$1 [R=301,P]
```